fossa-cli error: An exception occurred:RTextException PathPiece ""
I am running fossa-cli on a react app - and I keep getting this error at the end and I don't understand what it means.
Error: An exception occurred:RTextException PathPiece ""

I have the debug flag on and the project does scan successfully. However, I keep getting this error which is going to fail my pipeline.
I also looked at fossa-source code - hoping to get a hint but was not lucky.
Any idea what this could be?
Note that this is fossa-cli version 3.x - and fossa.yml has also been migrated to  v3. I also use yarn for package manager.
